# Android class ConnectionService

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Can anyone just give an example how to implement this abstract class- ConnectionService.my idea is to use TelecomManager to make an outgoing call.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html#SERVICE_INTERFACE

```
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
        PhoneAccountHandle accountHandle=telecomManager.getSimCallManager();
        PhoneAccount account=telecomManager.getPhoneAccount(accountHandle);
        telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(account);

        CharSequence label=account.getLabel();
        ConnectionRequest request = null;

        Connection connection= service.onCreateOutgoingConnection(accountHandle,request);
```

now i need to know what will be given in the request feild and Connection service how to implement before it..

Comment: You can make use of intent to make a call   startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phoneNumber, null)));

Comment: i need call to be made with the help of telecomManager. Not TelephonyManager

Comment: Were you able to find a good solution to access TelecomManager APIs and services? I am running into a similar issue, and any help with resolution would be helpful. Reason: I need to access the Connection Service to send dynamically generated DTMF Tones in active/initiated call, but the feature does not seem to be working using regular CALL intents.

Answer (score 8):

It's purpose is not for other apps to place calls. The supported method for doing that is through Intent.ACTION_CALL as stated in the other answer.

There is an API on TelecomManager to place a call, however, that is no different from sending the Intent directly.  More information about TelecomManager.placeCall: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/TelecomManager.html#placeCall

About ConnectionService:

The main purpose of the ConnectionService API is to include third party VoIP calls into the system dialer such that a cellular call and a third-party VoIP call can live side by side and the user can switch between them.  VoIP apps that implement this API benefit from this by having their calls treated just like traditional cellular calls including having them show up in the built-in system dialer/in-call UI, the call log, Android Wear support and Android Auto support.

If you were a third party VoIP app that wanted their calls to live side-by-side with traditional cellular calls, then you would:

1) Create an implementation of ConnectionService

2) declare that service within your AndroidManifest.xml file

3) Register a PhoneAccount with your ConnectionService component name

More information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html

The user is then able to turn on your particular phone account through dialer settings and your connection service is now an option for your user to place and receive phone calls through your own VoIP service.

Answer (score -2):

To open the dialer we need to use Intent and the action to be performed here is ACTION_DIAL, and data to be provided is the phone number, which initiates call explicitly. Below is the code snippet that performs this operation.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phnum));
```

phnum is the number to be dialed here got throught editText component. Finally, we should start the activity as shown below :

```
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Android permission to make call
This permission statement needs to be added to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: I need to use TelecomManager to initiate a call.. Not Telephony Manageer. I need to make two connections using TelecomManager and make conference.